# Can BigQuery data be accessed cross project?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-iam

Is it possible to allow someone to query a table from my bigquery without them seeing my project in their ‘select a project’ modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to allow someone to query a table without your project being seen under 'Select a project' modal. You just have to **provide permissions on a dataset or table level only**. See [sharing dataset document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls) and [sharing tables document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-access-controls) for more details.